# aws lambda with API gateway integration - accessing api name and type of http request

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm confused about how the amazon api gateway works. How does the lambda function have visibility of what API is being called and what type of HTTP request it represents?

For example, when running a web.py server locally, I'd enter the url app/api/getInfo?key=foobar and using web.py I'd be able to get the API name and body of GET request i.e. `{'key' : 'foobar'}` in JSON.

A lambda function has the following structure:

```
def test(event, context):
    # do something
    return response
```

Do I need to pass in the api name in the body of the request? Or is there a way to configure API gateway to get the API name through the event parameter? Same question for knowing whether it's a get or post method

Comment: read the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Gateway uses a "Lambda Proxy" Integration to invoke the Lambda Function. When the function is invoked, the web request object is passed to the Lambda Function as the **event** object. This object is a JSON dictionary and all parameters of the web request are passed in the **event** object. A detailed list of parameters can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format).

```
{
    "resource": "Resource path",
    "path": "Path parameter",
    "httpMethod": "Incoming request's method name"
    "headers": {Incoming request headers}
    "queryStringParameters": {query string parameters }
    "pathParameters":  {path parameters}
    "stageVariables": {Applicable stage variables}
    "requestContext": {Request context, including authorizer-returned key-value pairs}
    "body": "A JSON string of the request payload."
    "isBase64Encoded": "A boolean flag to indicate if the applicable request payload is Base64-encode"
}
```